# File not found google drive API

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to list files and trash some file from it but the update API throwing error **file not find**. Though list API is returning me the result and I am passing the same file id to the update API.

```
                    drive.files.list(
                      {
                        q:
                          "mimeType='application/zip' and name = '" +
                          prevFileName +
                          "' and '" +
                          parent +
                          "' in parents",
                        fields: "files(kind,id,name,mimeType,teamDriveId,parents,createdTime)",
                        corpora: "drive",
                        includeTeamDriveItems: true,
                        supportsTeamDrives: true,
                        teamDriveId: teamDriveId
                      },
                      (err, res) => {
                        if (err) {
                          console.log("Error listing files ", err.message);
                        } else {
                          const prevFiles = res && res.data && res.data.files;
                          console.log("prevFiles : ", prevFiles);
                          if (prevFiles && prevFiles[0] && prevFiles[0].name === prevFileName) {
                            drive.files.update(
                              {
                                fileId: prevFiles[0].id
                              },
                              { resource: { trashed: true } },
                              (err, result) => {
                                if (!err) {
                                  console.log("Prev file successfully deleted : ", result);
                                  resolve("File upload SuccessFully: ", file.data);
                                } else {
                                  console.error("Error removing prev file :: ", err);
                                }
                              }
                            );
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    );
```

Here I am getting a file with some json response

```
[ { kind: 'drive#file',
    id: 'ksnadoasjndajn12n1n212',
    name: 'xxx_x_x.zip',
    mimeType: 'application/zip',
    parents: [ 'xxxx-sandadaadakmke' ],
    createdTime: '2021-07-14T06:12:11.169Z',
    teamDriveId: 'xxxonaijsojxxx' } ]
```

But when I am passing this id in update API it is throwing error.
My Auth scopes are

```
var SCOPES = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly"
];
```

Please help me out in this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `drive.files.list` request contains `includeTeamDriveItems: true` and `supportsTeamDrives: true`, you should specify the respective option for [drive.files.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

By default `supportsAllDrives` is set to false unless you explicitly set it to `true`.

Thuss, files located on a team drive will not be found.

Note: `supportsTeamDrives` is deprecated, setting `supportsAllDrives` to `true` is enough.